# Последние сообщения в чате

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

У нас массив со списком id чатов — `[1, 2]`

**Задача:** из коллекции messages вытащить одно последнее сообщение в каждом чате.

Коллекция сообщений показана ниже.

`created_at` — время timestamp

```
[
  {
    chat_id: 1,
    text: '123',
    created_at: 1
  },
  {
    chat_id: 1,
    text: '123',
    created_at: 2
  },
  {
    chat_id: 1,
    text: '123',
    created_at: 3
  },
  {
    chat_id: 2,
    text: 'asd123',
    created_at: 1
  },
  {
    chat_id: 2,
    text: 'asd123',
    created_at: 3
  },
  {
    chat_id: 5,
    text: '123312',
    created_at: 1
  }
]
```

Запрос ниже не правильный, написал его чтобы была понятна суть.

```
db.message.find({chat_id: {$in: [1, 2]}}, {}, {
  sort: {created_at: -1},
  limit: 1
});
```

Такой должен быть результат:

```
[
  {
    chat_id: 1,
    text: '123',
    created_at: 3
  },
  {
    chat_id: 2,
    text: 'asd123',
    created_at: 3
  }
]
```

Прошу написать правильный запрос, чтобы я знал как это нужно делать.

И что будет, если у меня в коллекции messages будет 10 000 000 записей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужно фреймворк агрегации и оператор [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last) или [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/).;

- нужно фильтровать документы оператор [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) нам помагает это делать
- сортировать документы со `timestamp` в порядке убывания используя оператор [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)
- сгруппировать документы с помощью [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) оператор и возвратит последный документ каждой группы используя [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)

  ```
  db.message.aggregate([ 
      { "$match": { "chat_id": { "$in": [ 1, 2 ] }}},  
      { "$sort": { "created_at": 1 }}, 
      { 
          "$group": { 
              "_id": "$chat_id", 
              "text": { "$last": "$text" }, 
              "chat_id": { "$last": "$chat_id" }, 
              "created_at": { "$last": "$created_at" } 
          }
     } 
  ])
  ```

результат:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "text" : "asd123", "chat_id" : 2, "created_at" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 1, "text" : "123", "chat_id" : 1, "created_at" : 3 }
```

> что будет, если у меня в коллекции messages будет 10 000 000 записей?

это сработает но можно создать индекс в `created_id` чтобы улучшить производительность.